# Sublime Text 3 and Java with language server jdt-ls

Tags: java, sublimetext

I have downloaded the jdt-ls as language server and configured as described here https://lsp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#java

My project has source code which is in 'src/main' but sublime text (or jdt-ls) seems to assume that the source code lies in the root folder, i.e. every java file has a "wrong" package name. Is there a configuration for projects?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to set configuration options in individual projects, or which setting(s) you need to alter to change this behavior?

Comment: Yes. I need to point the source code which is 'src/main'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the root of the project there must exist a *.classpath* file. Here is my file for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main" output="bin/src/main"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test" output="bin/src/test"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  ...
</classpath>
```